# Print method parameter names where last parameter is a spread parameter in ES5

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to print to the console the signature of a method where the last parameter is a rest parameter in TypeScript (**ES5**) ?

for example the following method:

```
public execute(params1: number, params2: number, ...allOtherParams:number[]){
      // doSomething...
    }
```

should print out:

> execute(params1, params2, ...allOtherParams)

I am stuck at the rest parameter as the following solution does not show the rest parameter:

```
let funcSignature = this.execute.toString();
console.log(funcSignature);
```

I am getting this:

```
function (params1, params2) {
    var allOtherParams = [];
    for (var _i = 2; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        allOtherParams[_i - 2] = arguments[_i];
    }
    // doSomething...
}
```

```js
function execute(params1, params2, ...allOtherParams) {
  //doSomething
}

// The third parameter is not shown in console.log ?
console.log(execute.toString());
```

Comment: If I copy your code and run it in chrome, it works perfectly.

Comment: I guess in your tsconfig.json in **compilerOptions** section **target** option is set to **es5**. Try to set it to **es6** to get the result that you expect. For more details visit [TypeScript Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) page

Comment: @VladyslavYefremov yes I am using es5. Good to know that this works with es6. But unfortunately I can't change to project to es6.

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X this is probably because I use es5.

Comment: @VladyslavYefremov if you write as answer that this is only possible in es6 I will accept it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if typescript is compiled into **es6** (and higher) javascript standard.

For instance following typescript code:

```
function execute(params1: number, params2: number, ...allOtherParams:number[]){
    // doSomething...
}
```

When target is set to **es5** code is compiled into:

```
function execute(params1, params2) {
    var allOtherParams = [];
    for (var _i = 2; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
        allOtherParams[_i - 2] = arguments[_i];
    }
    // doSomething...
}
```

And when target is set to **es6** code is compiled into:

```
function execute(params1, params2, ...allOtherParams) {
    // doSomething...
}
```

Comment: do you know if there is a possibility to get the types of the parameters in TypeScript with ES6 ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a small modification to go:

```
function execute(params1, params2, ...allOtherParams) {
  //doSomething
}

console.log(execute.toSource().split('{')[0]);
```

It will print the beginning of your source which is exactly the signature.

Disclaimer: toSource is not for production websites since it is not standard and the behavior my change for different users.

Comment: I am getting the error: execute.toSource is not a function.

Comment: I just realized that even Chrome does not support this method but the Firefox(Gecko) do support.